# Opening a word doc from sharepoint, replace text and stream to user

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, ms-word

I want to be able to store a template word document in Sharepoint, and use it as a base for spitting out a word doc containing data injected into the template.

I can get the text of my word doc using code as follows:

```
    SPSite sc = SPContext.Current.Site; 
    SPWeb web = sc.AllWebs["MySite"];             

    string contents = web.GetFileAsString("Documents/MyTemplateWord.doc"); 

    web.Dispose();
```

Then I can string replace on the "contents" variable. This works fine.

I now want to "open" this new content as a word doc.

My code for this is as follows:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=MyWord.doc"; 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear(); 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders(); 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent(); 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment); 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/ms-word"; 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(outputText); 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I'm getting an error though, and not sure how to resolve it.

Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details: Error parsing near 'ࡱ>

Now clearly it has issues parsing the "string" content.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading a string, you are converting binary data to a string. 
(Rembember that a docx is a zip file containing xml data).
The nature of your approach to replacing the text is flawed in this regard.

If it were not for the desire to find/replace the text, I would recommend

```
using(SPWeb web = new SPSite("<Site URL>").OpenWeb())
{
    SPFile file = web.GetFile("<URL for the file>");
    byte[] content = file.OpenBinary();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(content);
}
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929265
Using a BinaryWrite to get the data to your page.

However, because you are using Word, I would recommend loading the document into an instance of the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open%28v=office.11%29.aspx).
However, using Word interop can be a bit of a time vampire.

Answer (score 0):

1- add docx assembly to your shaepoint package https://docx.codeplex.com

2- using Novacode;

3- note the following sample download button

```
  protected void ButtonExportToWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            byte[] bytesInStream;

            using (Stream tplStream =
                SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile("/sitename/SiteAssets/word_TEMPLATE.docx").OpenBinaryStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((int)tplStream.Length))
                {
                    CopyStream(tplStream, ms);
                    ms.Position = 0L;

                    DocX doc = DocX.Load(ms);
                    ReplaceTextProxy(doc,"#INC#", "11111111");

                    doc.InsertParagraph("This is my test paragraph");

                    doc.Save();
                    bytesInStream = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            Page.Response.Clear();
            Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +
                CurrentFormId + ".docx");
            Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytesInStream.ToString());
            Page.Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
            Page.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream);

            Page.Response.Flush();
            Page.Response.Close();
            //Page.Response.End();// it throws an error
        }

        private void ReplaceTextProxy(DocX doc, string oldvalue, string newValue)
        {
            doc.ReplaceText(oldvalue,newValue,false, RegexOptions.None, null, null,
                        MatchFormattingOptions.SubsetMatch);
        }
```